# How can files be excluded from merge operations using TFS and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I am trying to merge a development branch into a production branch while excluding the branched files in the development branch.

The file structure of my repository is as follows:

Dev branch - Contains file branches of a script (final, final-branch1, final-branch2) so multiple programmers can work on the same script at once. The final is reviewed by QA and put into the production branch at their discretion

Prod branch - Contains only the final version of the script (no file branches here)

I would like to be able to merge the entire dev folder into prod folder without bringing the branched versions of final over. I have tried the tfignore file, yet it is not working as expected. I am also using the Gui in Visual Studio 2017. Is there an easy solution to this issue other than merging one file at a time?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "branches" of a script. Do you mean you just have multiple copies of a file or folder **within** a real branch?

Comment: Yes, we have script folder based branching system for production and development and then we have file-based branches (copies) within the development branch folder. This is so we can have multiple programmers work on the same files at once. Yes, I know it is confusing and not the smartest thing, but that is how we do it. I would like those file branches not to be brought over when merging the development branch into the production branch